# Get linenumber for ElementTree Xpath match

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, elementtree

With lxml I can get the linenumber of referenced xpath match object:

```
>>> results = tree.xpath('.//field[@name="name"]')
>>> first_result = results[0]
>>> print(first_result.sourceline)
6
```

while by using SPL's ElementTree I can't find such method exposed to `.findall()` match objects.

Is there any way to get the linenumber of xpath match with SPL?

Comment: I doubt it . . . I'm guessing SPL means "Standard Python Library"?

Comment: With lxml you get the line number .. of what? The XML seems to be a tree that does not have line numbers really. If it is the line number of the original XML document: Line breaks are considered insignificant in XML, why do they matter in your case?

Comment: lxml gives the line number of original XML document. I need that information for my project limited to SPL.

Answer (score -1):

```
for txt in tree.xpath('//field[@name="name"]'):

    print(txt.sourceline)
```

Try this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).